# Custom Post Type "MUST NOT" be able to search via URL

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pods-framework

Hello good day everyone,

Guys any idea how to hide permalinks from custom post types and should not be able to access via url. By the way, Im using Pods framework for my CPT's

Example:
www.example.com/this-is-a-custom-post-type

Any suggestions, recommendation will be appreaciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just set the post type to not be public, and it won't be accessible via URL. In code it's done with a `'public' => false` argument, but I don't know what the option in Pods  looks like.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie  it still be able to query it via WP_Query?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't be able to link to it, because there'd be no URL.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

After creating a post type using pods, You can navigate to Advanced options and uncheck Public and Publicly Queryable.

Note: There are parameters like `exclude_from_search`, `publicly_queryable`, `show_ui`, and `show_in_nav_menus` that are inheriting value from `public`. You need to set them manually if you want to use them.

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

[image: Advanced options of pod's custom post type]

Comment: Thanks @Hector!!

Comment: @Hector - Is there anyway we can restrict the post to be rendered.
Example "https://example.com/<podName>/<postTitle>/attachment/<image-title>" should not be accessible.